# what is the equation of hyperbola that has eccentricity 2 center at the origin and focus at (1/2 , 0 )?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what is the equation of  hyperbola that has eccentricity 2  center at  the origin and focus at $(1/2 , 0 )$ ?

my answer is :

$4x^2-(16y^2)/3=1$

and **the choices don't contain this answer ?**

am I wrong?

or is there something else that I didn't understand it?

Comment: List out the choices from your book please.

Answer (score 1):

(4x^2)/1 − (16y^2)/3 = 1

Hence, a^2 = 1 and therefore a=√1 = 1

Also, b^2 = 3 and therefore b=√3

Using √(a^2 + b^2) / a to find e

e = √(1 + 3) / 1 = 2

The foci = (± ae, 0)
That means for your equation, (± 1 * 2, 0)
= (± 2, 0)

That means your answer is not correct. :( Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I would say that when eccentricity = 2 must be the focus (2,0).